# How to find the order changed duplicate contents in arrays using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
  For Ex : original array : a =[g,2,3,4,g,5] 
    if the user wrongly entered the above array like this :   a = [2,g,3,g,4,5]
```

How to find the position changed duplicated element from the original array list using javascript ?(i.e. [g,2,4,g] have been changed).

Comment: you need to eloborate your question , what you want do you want a changed array(difference btw both)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following, Here 'c' is another array in which you will be getting your required output

```
a =['g',2,3,4,'g',5] ;
b = [2,'g',3,'g',4,5];
c=[];

for(var i=0; i< a.length ; i++)
{
  if(a[i]!=b[i])
  {
    c.push(a[i]);
  }
} 
alert(c);
```